# Output id of parent cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched around and actually got help from another question similar to this on Stackoverflow however I can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to output the parent cell id when ever the user clicks on it. 
HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class='test' id='1'><img src='images/dog.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='2'><img src='images/cat.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='3'><img src='images/mouse.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='4'><img src='images/human.gif'/></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$('.test').on('click', 'td', function(e)
{ alert(this.id); })
```

Any help? also how would I go about displaying this as text on the page instead of an alert?

thanks

Comment: `$('.test').on('click', 'td',` makes no sense since they're the same element according to your code.

Comment: check out this http://jsfiddle.net/mvx3f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use event delegation here, also event should be delegated from one of static parents of the element, not the element itself, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // when DOM is ready
    $('td.test').click(function(e) { 
       alert(this.id); 
    })
})
```

If you want to set the value as text content of another element, you can use `text` method:

```
$('#element').text(this.id);
```

Comment: You should not say there is no need to use event delegation outright. There may be a huge need dependent upon how big that table is going to get. You need to listen for the event on the table if you do need event delegation.

Comment: Great thanks this works. Will accept when i get enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

You could add a div at the end of your current html like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class='test' id='1'><img src='images/dog.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='2'><img src='images/cat.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='3'><img src='images/mouse.gif'/></td>
<td class='test' id='4'><img src='images/human.gif'/></td>
</tr>
<div id='output'></div>
```

and change your alert to

```
$('#output').append(this.id + '<br>');
```

This will now create a row in your div with the id of the cell you clicked on.  Couple this with undefined's change to your event handler and you're all set.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't actually put the change to your event handler in the code, undefined covered that one perfectly fine, and it looks like we both edited our answers around the same time.  Me to point to his changed event handler and him to add the output to the screen requirement.